# Updating Dictionaries permanently in Python

Tags: python, json

I want to update the keys and values in my dictionary permanently, I have a dictionary stored in a variable, which has now 2 keys and values, I want to add keys and values, by input, and want them to be stored in the dictionary forever, even if I restart the program, What happens now is The keys and values given by the user are inserted successfully into the dictionary, but as soon as I restart the program, It is again back to the 2 values which I gave in the program.

Code:

```
      mails = {'robin': 'robin@mail.com', 'michael': 'michael@mail.com'}
      cont_name = input('Enter the contact name: ')  {Jessey}
      cont_mail = input('Enter the mail-id: ')       {jessey@mail.com}
      dict1 = {cont_name:cont_mail} 
      mails.update(dict1)
      print (mails)
```

(This gives me correct output)

Output:
{'robin': 'robin@mail.com', 'michael': 'michael@mail.com', 'Jessey': 'jessey@mail.com'}

but as soon as I Restart my program, and print the dictionary (mails), it shows me this output:

{'robin': 'robin@mail.com', 'michael': 'michael@mail.com'}

**Answers would be appreciated,
Thanks in Advance!**

Comment: Also I am in confusion because of this, Please clear it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21518024/python-save-content-of-a-file-txt-in-a-db-with-module-shelve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess pickle is a good solution for this.

```
import pickle, os
  
def load_emails(mail_file): 
    if os.stat(mail_file).st_size == 0:
        return {}
    mails = pickle.load(open(mail_file, 'rb')) 
    return mails

def store_emails(mails, mail_file):
    pickle.dump(mails, open(mail_file, 'wb'))                      

mail_file = "userdata"
mails = load_emails(mail_file)

cont_name = input('Enter the contact name: ')  
cont_mail = input('Enter the mail-id: ') 
mails[cont_name] = cont_mail

store_emails(mails, mail_file)
```

You need to call the `store_emails()` function every time you add a new key to the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Variables in Python are temporary. If you want them to be permanent, you could store the data in a JSON file or in your database. Or you could use Daweo's method, which I recommend, where you use `shelve`, a built-in Python module.

Comment: Thank you sir, but what should I keep in the file, - The dictionary format, or any other format??, Reply would be appreciated !!

Comment: You could store any type of data, even the whole dictionary.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

*want them to be stored in the dictionary forever, even if I restart the program*

You need what is called *data persistence*, you can use built-in [shelve](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html) module for that. Consider following simple example which provide favorite color of user if known otherwise ask for one and save it

```
import shelve
d = shelve.open("userdata")
name = input("What is your name?")
if name in d:
    print("Your favorite color is", d[name])
else:
    color = input("What is your favorite color?")
    d[name] = color
d.close()
```

where userdata is name of file where data are stored.

Comment: What should I keep in the file, - The dictionary format, or any other format?